# inserting canvas image into html string

Tags: html, mongodb, meteor, canvas

This Meteor server code tries to include a signature image which was created via `canvas.toDataURL()`. The signature needs to go into the html page before inserting the html string into a mongodb collection for the client to fetch and then `$(window.document.body).html(html);`.

All of my online reading speak of appending the canvas element to the DOM. Do I need to use cheerio to create the DOM then append then convert back to html string or there is a better way? How can this be done? Thanks

```
//server private method
signIt = (htmlStr) => {
  const signature = someCanvasElement.toDataURL(); //stored by method call
  if (!signature) return;

  let img = new Image;
  img.src = signature;
  let canvas = '<canvas id="sign"></canvas>';

  //how sure how to...
};
```

```js
//client
let w = window.open();
$(w.document.body).html(html);
```

Comment: Are you trying to render raw HTML in Blaze templates?  If so, you can simply do `{{{ signIt }}}`, where `signIt` would be a helper and would return the HTML string.

Comment: @CodeChimp No, it is rendered as ` $(window.document.body).html(html);`